# Understanding a sed command: sed 's/\s\s*/ /g'

Tags: sed, regular-expression

I came across this command:

```bash
ls -l <directory> \
  | tail -n +2 \
  | sed 's/\s\s*/ /g' \
  | cut -d ' ' -f 3 \
  | sort \
  | uniq -c
```

I'm not 100% sure if I understand the purpose of `\s\s*` in the `sed` option.

I know that `\s` is referring to a white space. Since the second `\s` precedes the `*`, this makes the 2nd white space match zero or more times.

Does this mean then that `sed` replaces one or more consecutive spaces from the input stream with a single space? If yes, why not just use `\s+` instead of `\s\s*`?

Comment: [Why *not* parse `ls`?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls)

Comment: @Cyrus No filenames are parsed here.

Comment: PS I noticed someone corrected the formatting of my initial post. Thanks! I will stick to this format in next posts. Cheers

Comment: @MikeB About that, see https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5308/tutorials-guidelines-on-posting

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`\s` is the GNU regular expression shortcut way to write the POSIX expression `[[:space:]]`, which matches any type of (horizontal or vertical) whitespace character (`\s` also matches newlines if these have been inserted into the pattern space of `sed` through other editing commands).  The `\s` notation originally comes from Perl regular expressions.

Some of the code below uses `[[:space:]]` although one usually *actually means* `[[:blank:]]`, which matches spaces and tabs only.

The command

```sh
sed 's/\s\s*/ /g'
```

replaces one or more consecutive whitespace with a single space and then repeats the substitution until no more matches are made on the current line.

So, yes, you could have used `s/\s+/ /g` instead, but that is an *extended* (GNU) regular expression rather than a basic one, so you would have to add `-E` to the command:

```sh
sed -E 's/\s+/ /g'
```

This now uses a non-standard option (`-E`) *and* GNU-specific regular expressions (`\s`).  To write the command in a standard-compliant way, you would have to use either

```sh
sed 's/[[:space:]][[:space:]]*/ /g'
```

or

```sh
sed 's/[[:space:]]\{1,\}/ /g'
```

where `\{1,\}` means the same as the extended regular expression modifiers `+` and `{1,}` ("one or more").

You could also use

```sh
tr -s '[:blank:]' '[ *]'
```

which would have done a similar thing, i.e. convert all spaces and tabs to spaces and squeeze (`-s`) runs of consecutive spaces into single spaces.  Note that using `[:space:]` would also replace newlines (and carriage-returns, vertical tabs etc.), which is probably not wanted.

Or, you could make `sed` do the job of `tail` in that pipeline and use

```sh
ls -l dir | sed '1d; s/[[:space:]]\{1,\}/ /g' | cut -d ' ' -f 3 | sort | uniq -c
```

Or, just use `awk`:

```sh
ls -l dir | awk 'NR > 1 { count[$3]++ } END { for (user in count) print user, count[user] }'
```

(With `awk`, you don't have to bother about squeezing the spaces)

Comment: So long story short: `+` is not POSIX/standard.

Comment: @mazunki The `+` modifier is standard in a POSIX extended regular expression. However, POSIX standard `sed` is currently only defined for _basic_ POSIX regular expressions, which does not support `+`. So, you can enable the use of `+` (which is a standard modifier) in `sed`, but only if you use a non-standard option.

Comment: Note that `\s` (any whitespace) generally stands for `[[:space:]]` while `[[:blank:]]` would be more like `\h` (horizontal whitespace only).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Yes, but no part of the pipeline is using PCRE. It's all GNU regular expressions, and `\s` is documented as "Matches whitespace characters (spaces and tabs)." (and embedded newlines, which doesn't occur here).  GNU regular expressions in `sed` does not have `\h`.

Comment: AFAICT, GNU `sed`'s `\s` on a GNU system at least matches on `\v` or `\r` for instance which are not matched by `[:blank:]` which is my main point, `\s` obviously inspired from perl is for matching whitespace, not horizontal whitespace.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas There seems to be a defect in the GNU documentation in that case (`info '(sed)regexp extensions'`).

Comment: Yes, gnulib's manual `info gnulib regu` also doesn't mention `\s`, even though that seems to be where GNU `sed` regexp engine comes from. From the source code, `\s` is the same as `[[:space:]]`

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Updated answer. Thanks!

Comment: You missed one s/blank/space/. The case of `tr` is more complicated as we'd need to exclude newline from the set.